# Aggegating duplicate records within SQL

Tags: sql, database

I need help aggregating duplicative records and summing their totals in the tables they exist. There is new data added every day to the table so the Database will also need to aggregate these records every time new data is entered.

Here is how the data is formated:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Agent ID</th>
<th>Agent Name</th>
<th>Work Record ID</th>
<th>Jan</th>
<th>Feb</th>
<th>Mar</th>
<th>Apr</th>
<th>...</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1234</td>
<td>Bob</td>
<td>1177</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>400</td>
<td>200</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5678</td>
<td>Phil</td>
<td>2586</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>400</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>300</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1234</td>
<td>Bob</td>
<td>1177</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>200</td>
<td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5678</td>
<td>Phil</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>200</td>
<td>400</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is an example of the desired results:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Agent ID</th>
<th>Agent Name</th>
<th>Work Record ID</th>
<th>Jan</th>
<th>Feb</th>
<th>Mar</th>
<th>Apr</th>
<th>...</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1234</td>
<td>Bob</td>
<td>1177</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>400</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5678</td>
<td>Phil</td>
<td>2586</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>400</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>400</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you share the DBMS you're currently using and your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: So the database table has a column for every month? Very questionable design.

Comment: yes there is a column for every month Jan-Dec

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply `group by` and `aggregate`.

```
select agent_id, agent_name, work_record_id, 
 sum(jan) as jan, 
 sum(feb) as feb, 
 sum(mar) as mar, 
 sum(apr) as apr
from your_table
group by agent_id, agent_name, work_record_id
```

You can see how cumbersome this will become if each month has it's own column. It would be much better if you had a single column with the date and another column with the amount.

Comment: so I also do have a date column in my table but the date is being recorded daily. In 10/17/22 we have one data set then in 10/16/22 there is another data set, and so on. Also it is worth to note that In my current sql query I have a where clause that specifies year (everything in 2022) related to the agents work team alignment. when adding the sum function as you mention I get ""Jan" is not a recognized table hints option."

Comment: If you have a date column, then your query could look something like: `select col1, col2, col3, extract(month from date_col), sum(amount_col) from .... where... group by .... ` . You just need to figure out how to extact the month from your date based on your RDBMS.